# Why reported "parsing error to physical plan" when dumping csv results in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: csv, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Why reported "parsing error to physical plan" when dumping csv results in Apache IoTDB?
When I tried to dump results of csv data files in Apache IoTDB, an error reported: "Cannot dump result because: 401: Error occurred while parsing SQL to physical plan:line 1:0 mismatched input '' expecting {CREATE, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER, REVOKE, LOAD, UNSET, FLUSH, REMOVE, MOVECOUNT, FULL, CLEAR, START, STOP, DEBUG}. What should I do about this?